# npx react-native run-android does not work. "java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"

Tags: react-native, gradle

Just recently ejected expo and I'm trying to run my app on an android device. I followed the instructions (hopefuly right) but I keep getting this error when I try to run my app:

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
```

Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

```
at makeError (C:\Users\User\Documents\jad for eject\jad\jad\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Users\User\Documents\jad for eject\jad\jad\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\User\Documents\jad for eject\jad\jad\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\User\Documents\jad for eject\jad\jad\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
```

Answer (score 16):

i am just using windows 7 32 bit i am also faced the same problem i solved like

you have local.properties file in your android folder or create one

in that file you  have give sdk dir path like

> give like this
>
> `sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\yourusername\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk`
>
> dont give like
>
> `sdk.dir=C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`

windows does not allow

Comment: THANK YOU, your approach help me to solve my issue.

Comment: Thanks my brother